# ScheduledExecutorService executes Producer thread only once

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

`ScheduledExecutorService` is expected to execute `Producer` every second with initial delay of 2 seconds.

**service**

```
public ScheduledExecutorService writeTimestampPeriodically() {
    executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    scheduleAtFixedRate(Producer.class);
    return executorService;
}
```

**Producer**

```
@Slf4j
public class Producer extends AbstractActor {

    public Producer(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(name);
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
        log.info("Produced {}", timestamp);
        queue.put(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**AbstractActor**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractActor implements Actor, Runnable {

    protected final String name;

    @Autowired
    protected Queue queue;

    @Autowired
    protected TimestampService timestampService;

}
```

**Actor**

```
public interface Actor extends Runnable {
    @Override
    void run();
}
```

**application.yml**

```
app:
  actor:
    producer:
      initial-delay: 2s
      period: 1s
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems like Spring not autowired correctly `queue` since it is null.

Moving

```
@Autowired
protected Queue queue;
```

to `Producer` didn't help.

**Queue**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class Queue {//...}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I think the problem is in the implementation of factory that creates `Producer` with `new`

```
@Component
public class ActorFactory {

    public Actor create(String name) {
        if (name.indexOf("consumer") == 0)
            return new Consumer(name);
        else if (name.indexOf("producer") == 0)
            return new Producer(name);
        else if (name.indexOf("monitor") == 0)
            return new Monitor(name);
        else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Actor Factory cannot create " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check on if it's throwing an error during excecution?

Comment: No errors or exceptions. Just one log record from `log.info("Produced {}", timestamp)`

Comment: And you put a try/catch around the entirety of the `run` method? Without any more context, my only guess is that `queue.put(timestamp);` threw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Spring's `Factory Beans` and `AbstractFactoryBean` cannot help in my case so I solved it like this:

**ActorFactoryConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class ActorFactoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public ActorFactory<String, Actor> actor() {
        return this::create;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    Actor create(String name) {
        if (name.indexOf("consumer") == 0)
            return new Consumer(name);
        else if (name.indexOf("producer") == 0)
            return new Producer(name);
        else if (name.indexOf("monitor") == 0)
            return new Monitor(name);
        else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Actor Factory cannot create " + name);
    }
}
```

**ActorFactory**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ActorFactory<String, Actor> {
    Runnable apply(String name);
}
```

**Actor**

```
public interface Actor extends Runnable {
}
```

**ActorService**

```
@Autowired
ActorFactoryConfig actorFactoryConfig;

@Autowired
private ActorFactory actorFactory;

private void scheduleAtFixedRate(Class<? extends Actor> actorType) {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            actorFactoryF.apply(actorType.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "-1"),
            getProperty(actorType, SETTING_TYPE.DELAY),
            getProperty(actorType, SETTING_TYPE.PERIOD),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```